# Convert Json Array to Strings

Tags: php, json

I have my result in json array format, I want to change my array results to json string format. How do I do this. Please help.. i dont have idea how i go about doing this :(. new to json
My result as json array is like this

[["Date.UTC(2011,09,03)","1"],["Date.UTC(2011,09,06)","53"],["Date.UTC(2011,09,07)","178"],["Date.UTC(2011,09,08)","305"],["Date.UTC(2011,09,09)","152"],["Date.UTC(2011,09,11)","20"],["Date.UTC(2011,09,12)","239"],["Date.UTC(2011,09,13)","25"],["Date.UTC(2011,09,14)","316"],["Date.UTC(2011,09,15)","169"],["Date.UTC(2011,09,16)","20"],["Date.UTC(2011,09,19)","126"]

My code

```
   $mysql_connect = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pword, $db_name);
    $query = "Select DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`,'%Y,%m,%d') as date, Count(*) as frequency               from mytable group by date_format(`timestamp`,'%Y,%m,%d')";
   if (!$mysql_connect)  die("unable to connect to database: " . mysql_error());

  @mysql_select_db($db_name) or die( "Unable to select database");

 $result = mysql_query($query);
 $response = array();
 if($result === FALSE)
{
   die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
       {  


    $date = "Date.UTC(".$row ['date'].")";
    $frequency =$row['frequency'];
    $response[] = array ($date,$frequency);


     }

 JSONArray jArray;
  String s = jArray.toString(); 

     mysql_close($mysql_connect);
```

Comment: You've got to be joking. https://www.google.com/search?q=php+parse+json

Comment: are you looking for php [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode):

```
<?php
$json_string = json_encode($your_array);
```

Did you even bother to Google this?